# ANOVA p-value changes depending on whether factors are used

Tags: r

I am running a standard ANOVA test on some experimental data.

```
data$group <- factor(data$group, ordered=FALSE)
analysis <- aov(output ~ group,data=vr2)
summary(analysis)
```

The output data is discrete (0-7) and the groups are numbered 1, 2 and 3. If I drop the first line, making the groups into factors, the p-value changes from 0.006 to 0.001.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Could you code up a repeatable example?

Comment: Truly discrete data shouldn't go into a general linear model, like an ANOVA. Neither should ordinal, which can sometimes be confused for discrete. Try a Poisson regression if discrete.

Comment: @Anonymouscoward Thanks for pointing this out! As posted below "t's a quiz response score, from 0-7, with a near-normal distribution from 1-6 and a peak at 7 (approx 25% of respondents). Any suggestions for this?" It's definitely not consistent with a Poisson distribution. Do you think it would still make sense?

Comment: @DarkLightA do the 0-7 carry any ranking order, or are they just unordered categories? As far as the test, it depends on what you designed your experiment to answer. You could use a non-parametric test, like a Kruskal-Wallis H, if you're looking for the ANOVA route. Again, I don't know your data, or the question you're investigating. You can get much better stats answers from [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I only play one on TV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if your dependent variable is discrete, then normal ANOVA is not a suitable model, because it assumes a continuous response variable. Which linear model is suitable depends on the type of data you are using (ordinal? counts?).

Second, `aov()` is, under the hood, just a linear model. When linear model "sees" a numeric variable, it simply runs a linear regression and not ANOVA as intended. Try the following code

```
x <- sample(1:3, 20, replace=T)
y <- rnorm(20)
summary(aov(y ~ x))
summary(lm(y ~ x))
x <- factor(x)
summary(aov(y ~ x))
```

Note the identical p-values from the first two models.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense! This is quite a bugger, good that it was caught! Regarding our data, unfortunately it's quite unnatural. It's a quiz response score, from 0-7, with a near-normal distribution from 1-6 and a peak at 7 (approx 25% of respondents). Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Factors which have levels that are numbers are notoriously confusing. Don't use them, use meaningful names or at least "X.1", "X.2" etc. (`paste0("X.", group)` ). Other bad things can happen - for example when the factor level "2" is the first factor level in your data. You see 2, but if you happen to interpret the factor as number, the 2 will become a 1.